# Parameter name conflicts with a property in the resource

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been getting this error after uploading a new version of my backend GAE app and it's really confusing me. I couldn't find anything online suggesting a remedy, and what's funny is that the program / method works just fine. So I'm not sure what the problem is:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backed method

com.google.api.server.spi.response.InternalServerErrorException: 

com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.PropertyParameterNameConflictException: 
myendpoint.com.packagename.classname.MyClassEndpoint.deleteSingle parameter regid: Parameter name conflicts with a property in the resource.
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.validatePropertyName(JsonConfigWriter.java:624)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.addBeanProperties(JsonConfigWriter.java:600)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.addBeanTypeToSchema(JsonConfigWriter.java:583)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.addTypeToSchema(JsonConfigWriter.java:567)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.addTypeToNode(JsonConfigWriter.java:668)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.convertComplexParameter(JsonConfigWriter.java:419)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.convertMethodRequestParameters(JsonConfigWriter.java:343)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.convertMethodRequest(JsonConfigWriter.java:319)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.convertApiMethod(JsonConfigWriter.java:307)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.convertApiMethods(JsonConfigWriter.java:280)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.convertApiMethods(JsonConfigWriter.java:266)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.generateForApi(JsonConfigWriter.java:124)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.writeConfig(JsonConfigWriter.java:103)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.getApiConfigs(SystemService.java:402)
at com.google.api.server.spi.BackendService.getApiConfigs(BackendService.java:98)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:164)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:125)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:45)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:234)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's my declaration for the method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "deleteSingle", path="delete_single", httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST)
public singleHolder deleteSingle(@Named("uid") String uid, @Named("regid") String regid, mydaoDAO t) {
```

Is it not allowed to use the "Named" property name to be the same as the "String" name? I see it used in this example under the heading "Path parameters":

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's allowed to use Named property value to be the same as the variable name.

So as you didn't attach mydaoDAO source, I only can guess. In my opinion there is a regid variable in your mydaoDAO class, and it conflicts with the Named regid property.
You should try to use another Named value for regid property.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I have a regid variable in my DAO class. I didn't know it wasn't allowed and haven't had a problem (nor any kind of warning or error) before.

What's the easiest way to resolve this? If I changed the @Named value for the regid property, wouldn't that affect the existing apps already using the old value?

Thanks

Comment: I just tried this. I renamed the value of one of my properties at backend, in my native client I used the original backend-android-enpoints.jar, and it works without any issue. 
But if you have any development version or environment, you should try it on that first. If it works fine, after deployment on the default version, I recommend to refresh the client also to avoid issues.

Comment: It's really strange that this error will occur now because I have been coding this way since I started the project 2 years back. Even stranger that the system works despite this error being thrown.

I have this on the live system and it's coded as such so I can't just issue an update to the clients immediately. Since it works I'll probably just let it be and slowly make the transition by renaming the @Named value. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Yes, it's really wierd. I had this issue also at getApiConfigs, but not all the time, it was random. Now as I checked the source of the generated client-libs, if I'm right, the value of the Named properties does not count, only the order of the parameters. So, if you change its value on the backend, it should not take an effect on the client side. Good luck!